# Windows physical drive access fopen and fseek

Tags: c, windows, file, fseek

I'm currently trying to access a physical hard disk as a stream of binary data in C.  I've mounted an image (.img), and it's readable from the OS (Win 7).

My C program simply attempts to open the physical drive in read-only binary mode, then read some data from the drive.

However, if I simply read data from the stream without seeking anywhere, all is well, I get back the data that is stored in the drive, and as I'm at offset 0 in the stream, I'm able to read the MBR on the disk.

However, if I try to `fseek` to any offset from the origin (zero), `fseek` return -1, indicating that it couldn't do it.

I'm guessing this might be a permission/ring 3/user level problem with accessing physical disks, and I'm probably going to have to write a driver to get kernel level access to do this, I'm just confused why I can read some data fine from the first sector, but I can't seek to any other offsets.  I've included part of the C program I've written below.

```
FILE *disk = fopen("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1, "rb+");
if (disk == NULL) {
    **error handle
 }
else { //Opened the drive sucessfully
fread(buffer, 1, 100, disk);
printf("Reading the first byte from buffer, it's:%d\n", buffer[0]);
//This works fine and I can read any byte within the initial buffer
int test = fseek(disk, 100, SEEK_SET);
printf("The value of fseek is:%d\n", test);
//This always returns -1, indicating the seek failed  
fclose(disk);
}
```

Comment: Can you read as long as you keep going from the start? Is it only the seek that fails? Or does read fail after a certain number of bytes?

Comment: I've just tried reading 512 bytes from the start, and then 2048, both read perfectly.  It's just the fseek that is failing.

Comment: I'm assuming seek to zero fails too. Sometimes there are messages in the Windows error logs. These are accessible through some tool in 'accessories' accessibly only to a machine admin.

Comment: Yes, seeking to zero also fails.  Each time I run the program, there is an error log written to the 'Administrative Events' log file, stating that: "The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable......" At least, they seem to be coinciding with the program being run.

Comment: try opening it in rb mode only instead of rb+.

Comment: Same thing with rb askmish.

Comment: and does the errno set to EINVAL when you do fseek?

Comment: I must confess my C knowledge isn't that great, so I don't know what you mean askmish :)

Comment: Try `_get_errno()` to get the errno. Also I would suggest you to check if the device you're reading is a block device or not. Use `_fstat()` for that.

Comment: A physical drive can only be read in multiples of it's sector size.

Comment: That's the problem, I was trying to read it in multiples of it's sector size :)

Comment: Try using the native functions (ReadFile and SetFilePointerEx) instead of the C-style functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from msdn:

If successful, `fseek` returns 0. Otherwise, it returns a nonzero value. On devices incapable of seeking, the return value is *undefined*. If stream is a null pointer, or if origin is not one of allowed values described below, `fseek` invoke the invalid parameter handler, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, these functions set `errno` to `EINVAL` and return -1.

Section 7.21.9.2 of the C standard [ISO/IEC 9899:2011] specifies the following behavior for fseek() when opening a binary file in binary mode:

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a
>   whence value of SEEK_END.

In addition, footnote 268 of Section 7.21.3 has this to say:

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with
>   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream
>   (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with
>   state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial
>   shift state.

A lot of low-level stuff matters, like sector alignment, file systems,etc. which needs a specific driver program to help navigating through the drives also need to be considered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks askmish.  I think for what I need to do, the logical partition access seems to work, so I shall use that for now, rather than trying to seek on the physical drive.  Thanks.